# C# FastReport: I Can't access forms from fast report file which his location in bin/debug

Tags: c#, fastreport

I am developing an application for sales management, its structure like the following:

```
sales_management -> UI -> (Forms here)
sales_management -> FReports -> (Fastreport files here)
sales_management -> bin -> debug -> (project file here)
```

Now when do "Copy always" option for fast reports in the FRports folder using VISUAL STUDIO it already moved into bin/debug

I added an click event with row of fastreport file but i cant access the forms inside UI. I used

namespace to reach these files and classes but it doesn't work.

here is the full report code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report ScriptLanguage="CSharp" ReportInfo.Created="05/20/2022 12:35:27" ReportInfo.Modified="02/11/2024 11:51:24" ReportInfo.CreatorVersion="2018.4.19.0">

<ScriptText>
  using System;
  using System.Collections;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.ComponentModel;
  using System.Windows.Forms;
  using System.Drawing;
  using System.Data; 
  using FastReport;
  using FastReport.Data;
  using FastReport.Dialog;
  using FastReport.Barcode;
  using FastReport.Table;
  using FastReport.Utils;      
  
   
  
  namespace FastReport
  {
    public class ReportScript
    {

      private void Cell27_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
             
      }
      
      private void Cell27_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
      {
           
      }
      
    }
  }

</ScriptText>
  
  <Dictionary>
    <TableDataSource Name="Entries" ReferenceName="data_set_of_entries.Entries" DataType="System.Int32" Enabled="true">
      <Column Name="id" DataType="System.Int32"/>
      <Column Name="description" DataType="System.String"/>
      <Column Name="is_forwarded" DataType="System.Boolean" BindableControl="CheckBox"/>
      <Column Name="entry_number" DataType="System.String"/>
      <Column Name="updated_date" DataType="System.DateTime"/>
      <Column Name="updated_by" DataType="System.Int32"/>
      <Column Name="doc_id" DataType="System.Int32"/>
      <Column Name="doc_type" DataType="System.Int32"/>
      <Column Name="show_balances_in_period" DataType="System.Boolean" BindableControl="CheckBox"/>
      <Column Name="debit" DataType="System.Decimal"/>
      <Column Name="credit" DataType="System.Decimal"/>
      <Column Name="document_type" DataType="System.String"/>
    </TableDataSource>
    <TableDataSource Name="Header" ReferenceName="data_set_of_entries.Header" DataType="System.Int32" Enabled="true">
      <Column Name="date_from" DataType="System.String"/>
      <Column Name="date_to" DataType="System.String"/>
      <Column Name="title" DataType="System.String"/>
    </TableDataSource>
    <Parameter Name="Parameter" DataType="System.String"/>
  </Dictionary>
  <ReportPage Name="Page1">
    <ReportTitleBand Name="ReportTitle1" Width="718.2" Height="103.95">
      <TextObject Name="Text1" Left="9.45" Top="18.9" Width="689.85" Height="37.8" Text="[Header.title]" HorzAlign="Center" VertAlign="Center" Font="Arial, 14pt, style=Bold"/>
      <TextObject Name="Text2" Left="9.45" Top="47.25" Width="689.85" Height="37.8" Text="من الفترة [Header.date_from] إلى الفترة [Header.date_to]" HorzAlign="Center" VertAlign="Center" Font="Arial, 10pt, style=Bold"/>
    </ReportTitleBand>
    <PageHeaderBand Name="PageHeader1" Top="109.28" Width="718.2" Height="37.8">
      <TableObject Name="Table1" Left="9.45" Width="699.87" Height="37.8">
        <TableColumn Name="Column1" Width="89.87"/>
        <TableColumn Name="Column2" Width="108.77"/>
        <TableColumn Name="Column3" Width="212.72"/>
        <TableColumn Name="Column4" Width="80.42"/>
        <TableColumn Name="Column5" Width="99.32"/>
        <TableColumn Name="Column6" Width="108.77"/>
        <TableRow Name="Row1" Height="37.8">
          <TableCell Name="Cell1" Border.Lines="All" Fill.Color="WhiteSmoke">
            <TextObject Name="Text6" Left="9.45" Top="9.45" Width="66.15" Height="18.9" Text="المبلغ" HorzAlign="Center" VertAlign="Center" Font="Arial, 12pt, style=Bold"/>
          </TableCell>
          <TableCell Name="Cell2" Border.Lines="All" Fill.Color="WhiteSmoke">
            <TextObject Name="Text5" Left="28.35" Top="9.45" Width="66.15" Height="18.9" Text="نوع القيد" HorzAlign="Center" VertAlign="Center" Font="Arial, 12pt, style=Bold"/>
          </TableCell>
          <TableCell Name="Cell3" Border.Lines="All" Fill.Color="WhiteSmoke" HorzAlign="Center" VertAlign="Center" ColSpan="2">
            <TextObject Name="Text4" Left="9.45" Top="9.45" Width="274.05" Height="18.9" Text="البيــــــــان" HorzAlign="Center" VertAlign="Center" Font="Arial, 12pt, style=Bold"/>
          </TableCell>
          <TableCell Name="Cell4" Border.Lines="All" Fill.Color="WhiteSmoke"/>
          <TableCell Name="Cell5" Border.Lines="All" Fill.Color="WhiteSmoke">
            <TextObject Name="Text7" Left="9.45" Top="9.45" Width="85.05" Height="18.9" Text="رقم القيد" HorzAlign="Center" VertAlign="Center" Font="Arial, 12pt, style=Bold"/>
          </TableCell>
          <TableCell Name="Cell26" Border.Lines="All" Fill.Color="WhiteSmoke">
            <TextObject Name="Text8" Left="9.45" Top="9.45" Width="122.85" Height="18.9" Text="تاريخ" HorzAlign="Center" VertAlign="Center" Font="Arial, 12pt, style=Bold"/>
          </TableCell>
        </TableRow>
      </TableObject>
    </PageHeaderBand>
    <DataBand Name="Data1" Top="152.42" Width="718.2" Height="37.8" DataSource="Entries">
      <TableObject Name="Table2" Left="9.45" Width="699.86" Height="37.8">
        <TableColumn Name="Column7" Width="89.87"/>
        <TableColumn Name="Column8" Width="108.77"/>
        <TableColumn Name="Column9" Width="212.71"/>
        <TableColumn Name="Column10" Width="80.42"/>
        <TableColumn Name="Column11" Width="99.32"/>
        <TableColumn Name="Column12" Width="108.77"/>
        <TableRow Name="Row2" Height="37.8">
          <TableCell Name="Cell27" Border.Lines="All" Fill.Color="White" Cursor="Hand" ClickEvent="Cell27_Click" MouseDownEvent="Cell27_MouseDown" Text="[FormatNumber([Entries.debit],2)]" HorzAlign="Center" VertAlign="Center"/>
          <TableCell Name="Cell28" Border.Lines="All" Fill.Color="White" Cursor="Hand" ClickEvent="Cell27_Click" MouseDownEvent="Cell27_MouseDown" Text="[Entries.document_type]" HorzAlign="Center" VertAlign="Center"/>
          <TableCell Name="Cell29" Border.Lines="All" Fill.Color="White" Cursor="Hand" ClickEvent="Cell27_Click" MouseDownEvent="Cell27_MouseDown" Text="[Entries.description]" HorzAlign="Center" VertAlign="Center" ColSpan="2"/>
          <TableCell Name="Cell30" Border.Lines="All" Fill.Color="White" ClickEvent="Cell27_Click" MouseDownEvent="Cell27_MouseDown"/>
          <TableCell Name="Cell31" Border.Lines="All" Fill.Color="White" Cursor="Hand" ClickEvent="Cell27_Click" MouseDownEvent="Cell27_MouseDown" Text="[Entries.entry_number]" HorzAlign="Center" VertAlign="Center"/>
          <TableCell Name="Cell32" Border.Lines="All" Fill.Color="White" Cursor="Hand" ClickEvent="Cell27_Click" MouseDownEvent="Cell27_MouseDown" Text="[FormatDateTime([Entries.updated_date], &quot;Short Date&quot;) ]" HorzAlign="Center" VertAlign="Center"/>
        </TableRow>
      </TableObject>
    </DataBand>
    <PageFooterBand Name="PageFooter1" Top="195.55" Width="718.2" Height="113.4"/>
  </ReportPage>
</Report>
```

And i tried to add this event

```
private void Cell27_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
      {
          EditForm frm = new EditForm();
          frm.Show();
      }
```

also used in above the namespace

```
  using sales_management.UI
```

It show me error that the app cant reach the UI files from fastreport folder which located in bin/debug or bin/release

Thank you